# What were the typographical rules for the title pages of New Latin books?

Tags: new-latin, typography

Many New Latin book title pages look like the following:

[image: title page]

What are the rules or at least the habits followed for which part of the title is either italicized, capitalized, etc.?
I guess it has something to do with the grammatical function of clauses but I'm not sure.

Comment: My instinct wouldn't have been that it has anything to do with grammar per se, but rather that it's just to distinguish titles/alternative titles, subtitles, additional information etc. I'm sure it owes more to contemporary trends in English book publishing than anything Latin-specific.

Comment: I don't get why you are referring to English trends, it's a book from 1731

Comment: My mistake, I hadn't read the cover, I should have referred to French trends as the book was published in France. My point stands though.

Answer (score 3):

This was not a Latin-specific trend, but a general typesetting trend in early modern Europe. For example, Robert Boyle's *Experiments, Notes, &c About the Mechanical Origine or Production of divers particular qualities* (1675) has a similar format:

[image: Scan of title page in a 1675 printing of Robert Boyle's Experiments, Notes, Etc]

As does Hauksbee's *Physico-Mechanical Experiments on Various Subjects* (1709):

[image: Scan of Haukbee's Physico Mechanical Experiments title page]

French titles used this style as well, for instance the *Journal des Voyages de Monsieur de Monconys* (1677):

[image: Scan of title page of Mons. de Monconys Journal des Voyages]

It was dependent on the printer and the location. Looking at Italy, the *Saggi* (essays) of the Accademia del Cimento (1666) used different colors and less variation in font:

[image: Scan of title page of the Saggi of the Accademia del Cimento]

I'm not sure if there was a convention for this sort of typesetting, but it was common and "trendy" at the time. It's not Latin-specific though, so you'd probably do better to ask this on the History SE.